# Intershop forms: Auto populating form fields when values are known

Tags: intershop

With both a Shipping and Billing address form to fill out, I would like to auto populate the second form with values from the first.

Currently, filling out the Invoicing address form does not populate the Shipping form if you choose to ship to a different address.  I'm hoping there's a BO setting allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sure that there is no such function. If both addresses have the same data then why wouldn't you just select that shipping and billing are the same though?